# How to output values that picks and adds values from multi inputs

Tags: c#, date

I need to output the following:
The date you entered is: Monday, May 16, 2017

I wrote:

```
namespace Date
{
    class Program
    {
        enum Day { Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun }; 
        enum Month { January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December }; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter Month in Numeric form (Example 1 for January): ");  
            Console.Write("Enter Day of the week in Numeric form (Example 1 for Monday): "); 
            Console.Write("Enter day in Numeric form (Example 15): "); 
            Console.Write("Enter year in Numeric form (Example 2018): ");  

        }
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to link the enum value with the number entered and print it out.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [C# documentation for enum types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum). It explains how you can assign your enum types integer values, which you could use to solve this issue. Also look at [Enum.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Enum_TryParse__1_System_String___0__), you can use that to parse strings to see if they match with any of the values in your enum.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and a totally over the top solution, assuming your `enums` are implicitly valued, you could use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/), [`Int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2), and [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Enum_IsDefined_System_Type_System_Object_)

**Given**

```
enum Day { Mon=1, Tue=2, Wed=3, Thu=4, Fri=5, Sat=6, Sun=7 };
enum Month { January=1, February=2, March=3, April=4, May=5, June=6, July=7, August=8, September=9, October=10, November=11, December=12 };


public static bool TryParse<T>(string input, out T result) where T : IConvertible
{
   // define default for worst case
   result = default(T);

   // if its not an int bail
   if (!int.TryParse(input, out var value))
      return false;

   // if its not defined in the enum bail
   if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value))
      return false;

   // yay convert and return true
   result = (T)(object)value;
   return true;
}
```

**Usage**

```
Month month;    
Day day;

Console.WriteLine("Enter Month in Numeric form (Example 1 for January): ");
while (!TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out month)) 
   Console.WriteLine("OMG you had one job");

Console.WriteLine($"You entered {month}");

Console.WriteLine("Enter Day of the week in Numeric form (Example 1 for Monday): ");
while (!TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out day))
   Console.WriteLine("OMG you had one job");

Console.WriteLine($"You entered {day}");
```

**Output**

```
Enter Month in Numeric form (Example 1 for January):
123
OMG you had one job
1
You entered January
Enter Day of the week in Numeric form (Example 1 for Monday):
3
You entered Wed
```

---

In short you can convert an `int` to an `enum` with a cast

```
Day day = (Day)SomeIntValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Date
{
    class Program
    {
        enum Day { Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun };
        enum Month { January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Month month;
            Day week;
            int day, year;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Month in Numeric form (Example 1 for January): ");
            } while (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out month));
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Day of the week in Numeric form (Example 1 for Monday): ");
            } while (!Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out week));
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter day in Numeric form (Example 15): ");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out day));
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter year in Numeric form (Example 2018): ");
            } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out year));

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The date you entered is: {3}, {0} {1}, {2}", month, day, year, week));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miller, how do you read this line? ("The date you entered is: {3}, {0} {1}, {2}", month, day, year, week)); what is {3}, {0} {1}, {2}  ? Thanks

Comment: It is the corresponding position of the coming variables. For more details, please refer to [String.Format Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2)